# load file on hover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to load an external file (using jQuery) when the user hovers a div. I tried loading it like a css file on hover but no luck. (Also, I can load a css file on hover, right? That code I tried for that is below.)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#f1_container2").hover(function () {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/supersized.shutter.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to load a second jquery file?

Comment: It's for a background image slide show that starts when you hover a div

Comment: This is not making any sense.

Comment: Oh OK, I misunderstood then - I thought you wanted to load a second `jquery.js`. So, have checked with firebug that the second file does not get loaded?

Comment: I don't see it getting loaded, and nothing happens when I hover over the div

Comment: If you want to do a slide show, then just use `Image` objects. What exactly do you want to load? Also, wouldn't it be easier to load everything you want at the begining, hide it and then show it at demand?

Comment: You should check your browser's network panel (Firebug or Chrome dev tools) and see if the browser is attempting to load the resource or not. If it isn't, try putting a console.log into the event callback to make sure the hover event actually fires. And yeah, make sure the file location is correct :P

Comment: How would I "hide it and show it at demand"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load content using $(".target").load("file.html"), where file.html is an HTML fragment containing some markup.

Since CSS is passive (it doesn't do anything until someone uses it), it can sit in the head in the first place. That way, when you hover over a div, you can do $(".target").addClass("newClass") to apply some groovy styling.

hover() can also take a SECOND function, which is invoked when the mouse leaves the target, so you can undo whatever you did on the mouseover.

Comment: This seems like the cleaner solution, mainly because adding a class/starting a script on hover is a lot easier/less resource intensive than loading a file.

Answer (score 0):

The document has already been loaded and rendered when you append the code for the stylesheet. The browser has already retrieved the needed resources and won't retrieve a file because you appended some code.

I would recommend, as mentioned, pre-loading your images or using another technique to retrieve the file on hover.

I believe something like this may work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#f1_container2").hover(function () {

         // The easy way
         //$('head').append('<img src="images/sprite.gif">');

         // The cool way
         var $img = $('<img>', {
             src:    'images/sprite.gif',
             load:   function() {
                 $(this).fadeIn('slow');
             },
             css: {
                 display:  'none'
             }    
         }).appendTo('body'); // append to where needed
    });
});
```